# How to use raw Pkcs#7 signature & user x.509 certificate to stamp it into a PDF file?

Tags: php, openssl, digital-signature, pkcs#7

I have a raw pkcs#7 signature response, user x.509 certificate & input hash of document to be signed. I need to stamp this  PDF. What is the process to get this PDF signed using above inputs?

Comment: First of all, what does your *raw pkcs#7 signature response* sign? Because for a PDF with integrated signature you don't need a signature of the original file but of signed ranges of a slightly extended pdf.

Comment: Basically I generate a hash value[sha256] of the contents of PDF file & sign request with my private key & digital certificate. In response I get a pkcs7 signature. Now I need to verify this signature response & stamp it into the PDF. Don't know how to go about this.

Comment: That kind of signing is OK if you want a detached signatures, not for integrated pdf signatures. You mention PDFBox by its tag, so why don't you use the pdfbox signing examples?

Comment: Ah, ok, removing the [tag:pdfbox] tag seems to push that solution off the table...

Comment: Does there exist a solution without pdfbox?

Comment: Yes. But as you use a [tag:php] tag, I assume you are looking for a solution for php, so using PDFBox requires something like a php-java bridge. I don't know about that. If there is something like that, though, you can simply use code from pdfbox signing examples. Probably, though, there also are PHP pdf libraries allowing you to sign pdf files without such a bridge...

Comment: @mkl can I get sample code in c# ..have same issue

Comment: How to use raw Pkcs#1 signature & user x.509 certificate to stamp it into a PDF file?

Comment: @MannanBahelim First of all choose an appropriate .Net PDF library. The rest depends on the library you choose.

Comment: do you have any sample code that use  itextsharp

Comment: @mkl Here is the code that my teammate has written https://stackoverflow.com/q/53313288/10655739

Comment: @Mannan that question shows a xml signature, not a raw PKCS1 signature. In particular there the data signed are a normalized xml stream. Thus, that signature is not usable for pdf signing.