# Why I am getting an error while opening digitally signed pdf document using PKCS7 and X509Certificate in C#?

Tags: c#, itext, digital-signature, x509certificate, pkcs#7

I am trying to sign a pdf file using `PKCS7` and `X509Certificate` but I get the following error when I open the signed pdf file in Adobe.

> *Document has been altered or corrupted since it was signed*

Docuement Hash

```
66305799d97adc716694faa3aecb3b82136a76a57e0470fb289dcf727b83304b
```

#### Following is my code:

```
public class Helper
{

    private static PdfPKCS7 _signature;
    private static PdfSignatureAppearance _apperance;
    private static byte[] _hash;
    private static byte[] _signatureHash;

    public static byte[] GetBytesToSign(string unsignedPdf, string tempPdf, string signatureFieldName, byte[] x509Signature)
    {
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(tempPdf))
            System.IO.File.Delete(tempPdf);

        var chain = new List<Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate>
        {
            Org.BouncyCastle.Security.DotNetUtilities.FromX509Certificate(new X509Certificate2(x509Signature))
        };

        Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate certificate = chain.ElementAt(0);

        using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(unsignedPdf))
        {
            using (FileStream os = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(tempPdf))
            {
                PdfStamper stamper = PdfStamper.CreateSignature(reader, os, '\0');

                PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = stamper.SignatureAppearance;

                appearance.SetVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(36, 748, 250, 400), 1, signatureFieldName);

                appearance.Certificate = chain[0];

                IExternalSignatureContainer external = new ExternalBlankSignatureContainer(PdfName.ADOBE_PPKLITE, PdfName.ADBE_PKCS7_DETACHED);

                MakeSignature.SignExternalContainer(appearance, external, 8192);

                Stream data = appearance.GetRangeStream();

                byte[] hash = DigestAlgorithms.Digest(data, "SHA256");

                var signature = new PdfPKCS7(null, chain, "SHA256", false);

                byte[] signatureHash = signature.getAuthenticatedAttributeBytes(hash, null, null, CryptoStandard.CMS);

                _signature = signature;
                _apperance = appearance;
                _hash = hash;
                _signatureHash = signatureHash;

                return signatureHash;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void EmbedSignature(string tempPdf, string signedPdf, string signatureFieldName, byte[] signedBytes)
    {
        using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(tempPdf))
        {
            using (FileStream os = File.OpenWrite(signedPdf))
            {
                _signature.SetExternalDigest(signedBytes, null, "RSA");

                byte[] encodedSignature = _signature.GetEncodedPKCS7(_hash, null, null, null, CryptoStandard.CMS);

                IExternalSignatureContainer external = new MyExternalSignatureContainer(encodedSignature);

                MakeSignature.SignDeferred(reader, signatureFieldName, os, external);
            }
        }
    }

    private class MyExternalSignatureContainer : IExternalSignatureContainer
    {
        private readonly byte[] signedBytes;

        public MyExternalSignatureContainer(byte[] signedBytes)
        {
            this.signedBytes = signedBytes;
        }

        public byte[] Sign(Stream data)
        {
            string strResp = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\Digital\Content\KYC_responseXML.txt");
            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDoc.LoadXml(strResp);
            string strDsc = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("EsignResp/Signatures/DocSignature").InnerText;
            return Convert.FromBase64String(strDsc);
        }

        public void ModifySigningDictionary(PdfDictionary signDic)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

#### Webservice returned following XML signature:

This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

```
<EsignResp errCode="NA" errMsg="NA" resCode="957C7BF1B9A9F1473E358F6F0D3FC200CB48A253" status="1" ts="2018-11-15T09:55:02" txn="UKC:eSign:5306:20181115095351206">
<UserX509Certificate>
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
</UserX509Certificate>
<Signatures>
<DocSignature error="" id="1" sigHashAlgorithm="SHA256">
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
</DocSignature>
</Signatures>
<Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<SignedInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
<SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/>
<Reference URI="">
<Transforms>
<Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
</Transforms>
<DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
<DigestValue>zcFiuaTy/HajJpSKCS/DtAZ8b+TMTPfO+Na7dLP38i4=</DigestValue>
</Reference>
</SignedInfo>
<SignatureValue>
qOJyQroX0Rr53prUuRSCAFKQZ77SOBXxM3x8iwk7GgrfOjdItK+/MMXes8K39Hy2jvzJuEtBai5nx4XiWrfHWThYcnkD/iuQb+Rs/NC9blJj5EdYSLlrZ6UAT2NYU70WKgbrteZiSgkk/PAyPTTwZzxtiExN5aPpalX0OkuHhrXnmvnssc4taaFNP3BfJ4JJphJiUgq02DLmCtvRI25Qg0H2kMpLZFiGNxCZTXck2hwDLpO8RVb9k6Fn8DZhWDWLEbEPNHb6CoAMsvTu7iSC9VMpq7c2scAeg2qVRFf63tmkAfbQZs7boWrmj96JwVj5P7K95UzH8ku+WehIm+8w==
</SignatureValue>
<KeyInfo>
<KeyValue>
<RSAKeyValue>
<Modulus>
0o9vohWZ3ztI9ea8D/zUEUBRq6c82BE7sFmr1hNMeuGSJQFf39ceesRtGUzlUYVWXcU23P8sVZ5419CHh7ApFzUXaLD72i/2d5FFI0n3iRlTQec9PEUHyrvOCVDpqBhbnrO/EHBqRluUQJTQUtMu5mhPNFV7IIJMTEAsUhCL9adZXXQK9NeK0foRr29Oq7VdEGfSeLzHIibpQmhNPh89oJXqu0cmbNSW4J4i2GmwHQpmsmHaSQcgh4mgVrykO64pAKXPreAPipDHQM1l/e5hilYlWfLHxhC5ObTCTcydQ218IVulFOFhdQt7xVV61TOmoTC2elhWbDqoLJBVU5mBfQ==
</Modulus>
<Exponent>AQAB</Exponent>
</RSAKeyValue>
</KeyValue>
<X509Data>
<X509SubjectName>
ITC INFRASTRUCTURE LIMITED
</X509SubjectName>
<X509Certificate>
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
</X509Certificate>
</X509Data>
</KeyInfo>
</Signature>
</EsignResp>
```

Comment: Your service returns a xml signature but you need a cms signature. I doubt very much you can use your sign service response to generate a valid pdf AcroForm signature.

Comment: signature response can be any one from these i.e. rawrsa,pkcs7,rawecdsa . among these which response type should I use ?

Comment: if I pass rawrsa and rawecds as response type . I get new error "Error during signature verification.  

Error encountered while BER decoding:" in both cases

Comment: I don't know that service, in particular I don't know what "rawrsa,pkcs7,rawecdsa" exactly mean. What you need is that your service either returns a properly-profiled cms signature container or a PKCS1 signature of exactly the given hash (not of some XML fragment that somewhere contains that hash). In the latter case you also should know the signer certificate beforehand to be able to add ESS certificate identification to the signed attributes. Depending on which data your service returns exactly, you have to change your existing code one way or the other.

Comment: <DocSignature> attr contain PKCS1 signature

Comment: Ok. In that case, do you know the signer certificate beforehand?